# SQL connection to server with QlikView

Tags: qlikview

I want to connect to a server to obtain data with QlikView, unfortunately I have this error:

`ErrorSource: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers, ErrorMsg: [Microsoft][Gestionnaire de pilotes ODBC] Valeur d'argument non valide OLEDB CONNECT TO [Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties="DRIVER=KISAM 32 bit driver;UID=wamr;SERVER=x.x.x.x,790;DBNAME=theName;SHCOL=Y;LUID=wamr;"]`

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Did QV create that connection string? If not try to recreate the connection string in the script editor by selecting OLEDB, press connect and insert connection details.

Comment: Thank you mickeger

Answer (score 0):

Putting my comment as an answer;

Did QV create that connection string? If not try to recreate the connection string in the script editor by selecting `OLEDB`, press `connect` and insert connection details.